# How to extract a group of values from a list after finding the group with the best "score", using python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list ('dummy"). I want to extract ONLY the values related to the best 'Score'. For example, from the list I should have the following values extracted:

```
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: inception_v4_299_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 121.8",
    "Time(ms): 101.2",
    "Inference: admiral",
    "Score: 0.59375 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.05",
```

Why? Because "Score: 0.59375 ", is the highest value when compared to the other "Scores" in the list.

How can I do that?

Thank you

THE CODE

```
#This is the list

dummy = ['labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 23.1\n', 'Time(ms): 5.7\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: corkscrew, bottle screw\n', 'Score: 0.03125 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.05\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-M_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 29.3\n', 'Time(ms): 10.8\n', '\n', '\n', "Inference: dragonfly, darning needle, devil's darning needle, sewing needle, snake feeder, snake doctor, mosquito hawk, skeeter hawk\n", 'Score: 0.09375 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 56.8\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-L_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 45.6\n', 'Time(ms): 31.0\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: pick, plectrum, plectron\n', 'Score: 0.09766 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.55\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: inception_v3_299_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 68.8\n', 'Time(ms): 51.3\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: ringlet, ringlet butterfly\n', 'Score: 0.48047 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.3\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: inception_v4_299_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 121.8\n', 'Time(ms): 101.2\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: admiral\n', 'Score: 0.59375 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.05\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: inception_v2_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 34.3\n', 'Time(ms): 16.6\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: lycaenid, lycaenid butterfly\n', 'Score: 0.41406 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.3\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 14.4\n', 'Time(ms): 3.3\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: leatherback turtle, leatherback, leathery turtle, Dermochelys coriacea\n', 'Score: 0.36328 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.3\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 14.5\n', 'Time(ms): 3.0\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: bow tie, bow-tie, bowtie\n', 'Score: 0.33984 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.3\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: inception_v1_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 21.2\n', 'Time(ms): 3.6\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: pick, plectrum, plectron\n', 'Score: 0.17578 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.3\n', '##################################### \n', '\n']


### This is to clean the data

regex = re.compile(r'(\w+)\((.+)\):\s(.*)|(\w+:)\s(.*)')
match_regex = list(filter(regex.match, dummy))
match = [line.strip('\n').strip() for line in match_regex]  
print("match list", match, "\n")
```

THE 'dummy' LIST LOOKS LIKE THIS

```
[
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 23.1",
    "Time(ms): 5.7",
    "Inference: corkscrew, bottle screw",
    "Score: 0.03125 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.05",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-M_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 29.3",
    "Time(ms): 10.8",
    "Inference: dragonfly, darning needle, devil's darning needle, sewing needle, snake feeder, snake doctor, mosquito hawk, skeeter hawk",
    "Score: 0.09375 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 56.8",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-L_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 45.6",
    "Time(ms): 31.0",
    "Inference: pick, plectrum, plectron",
    "Score: 0.09766 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.55",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: inception_v3_299_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 68.8",
    "Time(ms): 51.3",
    "Inference: ringlet, ringlet butterfly",
    "Score: 0.48047 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.3",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: inception_v4_299_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 121.8",
    "Time(ms): 101.2",
    "Inference: admiral",
    "Score: 0.59375 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.05",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: inception_v2_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 34.3",
    "Time(ms): 16.6",
    "Inference: lycaenid, lycaenid butterfly",
    "Score: 0.41406 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.3",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 14.4",
    "Time(ms): 3.3",
    "Inference: leatherback turtle, leatherback, leathery turtle, Dermochelys coriacea",
    "Score: 0.36328 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.3",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 14.5",
    "Time(ms): 3.0",
    "Inference: bow tie, bow-tie, bowtie",
    "Score: 0.33984 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.3",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: inception_v1_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 21.2",
    "Time(ms): 3.6",
    "Inference: pick, plectrum, plectron",
    "Score: 0.17578 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.3",
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Given `dummy` as a list
- `dummy[6::8]` the first `'score'` is at index 6, and then every 8th from there.

```py
scores = [float(v.split(': ')[1]) for v in dummy[6::8]]  # extract the scores and convert them to floats
idx = scores.index(max(scores))  # find the index of the max (best) score
n = 8  # size of each group
group = [dummy[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(dummy), n)][idx]  # split dummy into groups and select the group at idx 

# print(group)
['labels: imagenet_labels.txt ',
 'Model: inception_v4_299_quant_edgetpu.tflite ',
 'Image: insect.jpg ',
 'Time(ms): 121.8',
 'Time(ms): 101.2',
 'Inference: admiral',
 'Score: 0.59375 ',
 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.05']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one.

```
from operator import itemgetter

dict_array = []
cur_dict = {}
for item in dummy:
    key, val = item.split(":")
    cur_dict[key.strip()] = val.strip()
    if key == "TPU_temp(°C)":
        dict_array.append(cur_dict)
        cur_dict = {}

return_array = sorted(dict_array, key=itemgetter('Score'), reverse=True) 
print(return_array[0])
```

The result is as the following.

```
{'labels': 'imagenet_labels.txt', 'Model': 'inception_v4_299_quant_edgetpu.tflite', 'Image': 'insect.jpg', 'Time(ms)': '101.2', 'Inference': 'admiral', 'Score': '0.59375', 'TPU_temp(°C)': '57.05'}
```

Hope it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

If `dummy` is your list from your question:

```
import re

groups = []
for v in dummy:
    if v.startswith('labels:'):
        groups.append([v])
    else:
        groups[-1].append(v)

max_group = max(groups, key=lambda k: float(re.search(r'Score: ([\d.]+)', ' '.join(k)).group(1)))

print(*max_group, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
labels: imagenet_labels.txt 
Model: inception_v4_299_quant_edgetpu.tflite 
Image: insect.jpg 
Time(ms): 121.8
Time(ms): 101.2
Inference: admiral
Score: 0.59375 
TPU_temp(°C): 57.05
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a dictionary instead of the list you are showing, BUT you could do it like this with the current setup you have:

assuming your list name is x then you can:

```
max_score = 0
pos = 0
for element in x:
    if "Score" in element:
        if max_score<=(float(element[7:])): # the text is always in the same position, you could use a regular expression instead 
            max_score = float(element[7:])
            max_pos = pos
    pos+=1

print(x[max_pos-6:max_pos+1])
```